# How to compile Python 1.0

Tags: python, installation, legacy

For some perverse reason, I want to try Python 1.0.. How would I go about compiling it, or rather, what is the earlier version that will compile cleanly with current compilers?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.5, although since it's for nothing more than curiosity (about how the language has changed), compiling in a Linux virtual machine is possible too..

Comment: Are you receiving any particular errors?

Comment: -1: No errors.  No sample script being used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 1.0.1 compiles perfectly under Ubuntu 8.10 using GCC 4.3.2. It should compile under Leopard, too.

Download the source [here](https://legacy.python.org/download/releases/src/python1.0.1.tar.gz), and compile the usual way:

```
./configure
make
```

**UPDATE:** I tested it, and it compiles under Leopard, too.

Comment: The oldest release I could find on python.org was 1.0.1.

Comment: From python.org: "If you find an older Python release (e.g. 0.9.8), we're interested in getting a copy!"

Comment: Opps.. I originally tried (a week or two ago) from the git-svn imported Python SVN, which seemed to be missing files. Odd. The source tarball compiles perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I am getting the following error `No rule to make target '../Objects/libObjects.a', needed by '../python'` on Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Going further backwards in time, I pulled the 0.9.1p1 source from alt.sources via Google Groups' archive. That's 18+ year old code!

I made a few changes (documented in README.reconstructed) to get it to compile on my OS 10.4 box. [Source available](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2009/03/27/python_0_9_1p1.html) for your enjoyment. I've also sent email to python.org maintainers to see if they want a copy of it.

It doesn't compile cleanly. There are some warnings, mostly to do lack of prototypes. But it does work.